# Conjugating of root subspaces by exponents

Tags: representation-theory, semisimple-lie-algebras

$\renewcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
\newcommand{\brc}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\Aut}[2]{\operatorname{Aut}_{#1}\brc{#2}}
\renewcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\brr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}$
Let $L$ be a complex semisimple finite dimensional Lie algebra with a finite dimensional faithful representation $V$. As known,
$$
L=H\bigoplus_{\alpha\in\Phi}L_\alpha,
$$
where $H$ is a Cartan subalgerba, $\Phi$ is a root system and $L_\alpha=\bra{e_\al}$ are one dimensional root subspaces. Let $\brc{-,-}$ be the Killing form on $L$. Since $(-,-)$ is a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $H$, we can fix an isomorphism $H\to H^*$ by $t_\lambda\mapsto \lambda=\brc{t_\lambda,-}$. Now let $(\lambda,\mu)=\brc{t_\lambda,t_\mu}$ for $\lambda,\mu\in H^*$. This gives a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $H^*$. Let $\si_\al$ be the reflection in the hyperplane orthogonal to $\al$ in $H^*$. Also define $\bra{\lambda,\mu}=2\frac{\brc{\lambda,\mu}}{\brc{\mu,\mu}}$ for $\lambda,\mu\in H^*$.

Since $e_\al$ are nilpotent operators on $V$, for $r\in\C\setminus\{0\}$ we can define operators in $\Aut{}{V}$ by
$$
x_\al(r)=\exp\brc{re_\al}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{r^i}{i!}e_\al^i,\qquad w_\al(r)=x_\al(r) x_{-\al}\brc{-\frac{1}{r}}x_\al(r).
$$

**The question**. Why there is some $c\in\C$ such that $w_\al(r)e_\beta w_\al(r)^{-1}=cr^{-\bra{\beta,\al}}e_{\si_\al\brc{\beta}}$ as operators on $V$ for roots $\al$, $\beta$?

**Motivation**. Want to understand the proof of the (a) in the proof of Lemma 19 in R. Steinberg's *Lectures on Chevalley Groups*.

**Attempt**. In the proof it is said that we should apply

*Lemma 19 (b)*. If $v\in V_\mu$ then there exists $v'\in V_{\si_\al\brc{\mu}}$ independent of $r$ such that $w_\al(r)v=r^{-\bra{\mu,\al}}v'$. Here $V_\lambda$ for $\lambda\in H^*$ are weight subspaces of $V$.

to the adjoint representation of $L$. Then for some $c\in\C$ we have
$$w_\al(r)e_\beta w_\al(r)^{-1}=\brc{\brr{w_\al(r),e_\beta}+e_\beta w_\al(r)}w_\al(r)^{-1}=e_\beta+r^{-\bra{\beta,\al}}ce_{\si_\al\brc{\beta}}w_\al(r)^{-1},
$$
by *Lemma 19 (b)*. However, have no idea how to proceed.